# Shared template in angular.js with routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a loading div that I'd like to share across several controllers.  Is there a way to accomplish this without placing this template in every other template?

For example:

```
<div ng-show="loading" class="loading">Loading</div>
```

Now in my controller I turn this off and on my using `$scope.loading = true/false.`

In my main page I use this:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using routing so, right now I have to place the loading div in each template that is called by the router so it is inserted in ng-view.  All I want is one location for the loading div. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Set up the loading div as a custom directive, check out this example from the angularjs documentation:

```
angular.module('docsSimpleDirective', [])
.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.customer = {
    name: 'Naomi',
    address: '1600 Amphitheatre'
  };
}])
.directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    template: 'Name: {{customer.name}} Address: {{customer.address}}'
  };
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

There's quite a few ways to do this.

What I've come up with is to use a service to register an AppController callback. Then in each of my page's controllers I inject that service, and call the callback with true/false.

The full code is below, but the main lines to focus on is:

```
myApp.service('LoadingService', function() {
  var controllerCallback = function() {};
  this.setControllerCallback = function(callback) {
    controllerCallback = callback;
  };

  this.setLoading = function(bool) {
    controllerCallback(bool);
  };
});
```

And in your AppController:

```
LoadingService.setControllerCallback(function(bool) {
  $scope.loading = bool;        
});
```

Then to show the loading div, just inject that service into a controller and call

```
LoadingService.setLoading(true) //or false
```

This allows for the service to be reused in any controller that needs to toggle the loading div.

```js
// Code goes here
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/page1', {
      templateUrl: 'page1.html',
      controller: 'PageOneController'
    })
    .when('/page2', {
      templateUrl: 'page2.html',
      controller: 'PageTwoController'
    })
});

myApp.controller('AppController', function($scope, LoadingService) {
  $scope.loading = false;

  LoadingService.setControllerCallback(function(bool) {
    $scope.loading = bool;        
  });
});

myApp.controller('PageOneController', function($timeout, LoadingService) {
  LoadingService.setLoading(true);

  $timeout(function() {
    LoadingService.setLoading(false);
  }, 2000);
});

myApp.controller('PageTwoController', function($timeout, LoadingService) {
  LoadingService.setLoading(true);

  $timeout(function() {
    LoadingService.setLoading(false);
  }, 3000);
});

myApp.service('LoadingService', function() {
  var controllerCallback = function() {};
  this.setControllerCallback = function(callback) {
    controllerCallback = callback;
  };

  this.setLoading = function(bool) {
    controllerCallback(bool);
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>

</head>

<body ng-controller="AppController">
  <h1>Title</h1>

  <a href="#/page1">Page 1</a>
  <a href="#/page2">Page 2</a>

  <div ng-if="loading">Loading...</div>
  <div ng-view></div>

  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular-route.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="page1.html">
    <div>You're on page one</div>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="page2.html">
    <div>You're on page two</div>
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```